# Broken images in bootstrap carousel- Django production(nginx, gunicorn)

Tags: django, nginx, carousel, gunicorn, production-environment

I'm setting up a website for production and everything seems alright except that I'm getting broken images in bootstrap carousel(the only place where I have images). I've ran collectstatic and a new folder is created in the project directory where manage.py exists. I've other js, css all working well. Below are my changes in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/xyz/myprojectenv/myproject/static/'
```

and nginx sites-available files

```
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/xyz/myprojectenv/myproject/static/;
}
```

and html template

```
{% load static %}
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">

<div class="item active">

  <img src="{% static "img1.png" %}" alt="img1-name" class="tales">
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="{% static "img2.png" %}" alt="img2-name" class="tales">
</div>
```

broken-image example:

[image: x]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.

In nginx/sites-available/myproject file, use:

`location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; } location /static/ { root /home/xyz/myprojectenv/myproject/; }`

Instead of this:

`location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; } location /static/ { root /home/xyz/myprojectenv/myproject/static/; }`

Cheers!!